# Is there any way I can see a reason why my flag was disputed

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, triage, disputed-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29769872/2987066) as "Unclear what you as asking" and when looking back at my flags it is marked as "Disputed", which I am fine about as other people must have seen something I have not.

But is there any way I can see a reason why my flag was "Disputed"? Perhaps I had flagged it for the wrong reason for example? I believe that if I were educated as to why it was disputed it could help my flagging in the future

Comment: I'd guess that the [Triage review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7771197) of the question (Looks OK X 3) disputed your flag.

Comment: @bluefeet how did you get to the Triage review page for that question?

Comment: I took a shortcut and used one of the mod tools.

Comment: @bluefeet,I wish there was a way for us mere mortals to do that.. Often I find myself wanting to go to the triage item for a question.

Comment: @JonasCz I agree, Would have definitely help the user identify how many people disputed / agreed with a flag (although in this case it wouldn't of helped as everyone put "Looks Ok" anyway)

Comment: You can access the reviews for a post through this query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203969/find-the-reviewtasks-for-a-post However, it does not appear yet (since the data is loaded I think once per week)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Perhaps I had flagged it for the wrong reason for example? I believe that if I were educated as to why it was disputed it could help my flagging in the future

It's definitely worth revisiting reviews and flags that are disputed/declined to see what you can learn, but in this case I would say you were right and the other folks were wrong.

The question was:

> I have local wcf service and client C# application works well. But php code fails. How to make it work?

followed by walls of code with no explanation of what that code is trying to do. There is a stack trace, but the OP didn't respond to a comment asking for clarification. "Unclear what you are asking" was the right call.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there any way I can access the Triage review without the mod tools? (I'm sure I used to be able to from the Flags page) as I could see how many people agreed / disagreed with my flag

Comment: @user1 Unfortunately the review queues have a separate id number than post id, so there's no direct link. You can go to the [review history page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history) and click the "my review history" link at the bottom right to see your own recent reviews. The links in the 3rd column take you to the summaries.